# Can't find ole object

Tags: .net

I need a System.Net.IPAddress object to work. For example, I found the System.random object viewer through the Ole/Com Object Viewer, but System.Net.IPAddress is not there, the project does not see it either, what should I do?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do and **why** you want to use .NET objects via COM/OLE.

Comment: my project is written in an unusual programming language. It does not have functionality for obtaining an IP address, but it does have functionality for working with ole objects

Comment: Very few .NET types are exposed to COM/OLE - you'll need to create a new .NET Class Library project ([with `[assembly: COMVisible]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute) that re-exports the .NET types you want to use behind a new `interface`.